# Can't start Sublime Text with gksu

Tags: linux-mint, sublime-text, gksudo

`Sublime Text 3` is my primary text editor. I run it as a regular user, but once in a while I need to start is as root to edit some system files. I am used to having `edit as root` in my context menu on my old system.

In my old Linux Mint 13 Maya I used 'gksu subl'. In my new Linux Mint 17 Qiana this does not work. Here is what happens:

When I execute `gksu subl` I am prompted for a password with a graphical dialog. I enter the password which is accepted and then nothing happens. Command returns. No error message, no other indications of failure, but `Sublime Text` doesn't start.

Note, I am sure that `gksu` is present and working because `gksu gedit` works as expected - it asks for a password and then starts `gedit` with root privileges.

Also if I open the my file manager (Nemo) with root privileges and browse to text file and just double click it - the file opens in `Sublime Text` with root privileges. So I am sure that root can run `Sublime Text`.

Also if I try `sudo subl`, it works, but I don't want to use this as a solution for obvious reasons.

The problem seems to be specific to launching `Sublime Text` with `gksu` in Mint 17

Any ideas about why `Sublime Text` does not start with `gksu` and how to fix it?

Please do not suggest workarounds like "Use different text editor" and "launch file manager with `gksu` and then just open the text file for editing", I am looking for the solution to this particular problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. For some reason (probably bug), Sublime Text is exiting with success code right after starting, when it is started with gksu. To prevent this from happening I used `-w` argument passed to `subl` on startup

```
smc@smc-comp ~ $ subl --help Sublime Text build 3065

Usage: sublime_text [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: sublime_text [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories

Arguments:
--project <project>: Load the given project
--command <command>: Run the given command
-n or --new-window:  Open a new window
-a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
-w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning 
-b or --background:  Don't activate the application
-h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
-v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific location.
```

So the command looks like this:

```
gksu "subl -w %F"
```

Maybe this will save someone time looking at the same issue